# How can I use USB3.0 cable for Ethernet (4 signals), USB2.0 (4 signals), 12 V and ground?

Tags: usb-3

I am making a quick prototype where it needs 10 wires for Ethernet (4 signals), USB2.0 (4 signals), 12 V and ground. Without spending money at this stage, I am trying to see if I can use USB 3.0 cable where it has 2 pairs of differential signals (to be used with Ethernet), dp & dm for USB 2.0 and +-(12 V). The cable length is about 1 meter.

Will it work if I use USB 3.0 cable for my situation? If it is not a good idea, I will use 3 cables for each signal and power.

Comment: Consider what would happen if you inserted the cable the other way round? Might it cause a short or power to be present on a pin that can't handle it.

Comment: Do you mean a cable for Type-C? Do you plan to chop off the connectors and use the cable only? Did you forget the 5V of USB2? How much current you require?

Comment: Looks like I missed the most important information. I will use the cable only. The board has 12v to 5v. The connector side uses LEMO 12pin on one end and the other end is 12v power + USB 2.0 + ethernet split from the USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is wise to use signal levels (+12V) on a port where this is typically not expected and can cause damage. Especially on ports easily mistaken for other features.

In general, do not reuse common ports!

But if you want to, perhaps you could use an HDMI cable.
It is rated for high signal speeds and has plenty of pins outside the 4 signal pairs.
Most importantly, it is not reversible as @scotty3785 rightfully mentions.
If you plug in a Type A to Type C cable you have a bad day.

Comment: HDMI cables are not rated for power. USB cables are. And also will do damage if 12V plugged to an actual HDMI device. And you can always arrange your signals symmetrically so 12V isn't a problem, plugging it accidentally to a device will always be a problem with any connector re-used for custom purposes.

Comment: OP does not seem to imply he will use +-12V for signals. As I understand it, this is simply the power. The signals are just USB DP/DM and ethernet pairs. And some USB cables and ports *are* rated for 12V for VBUS/GND. USB-C with power delivery can actually deliver up to 48V. This is within specs, if cables and ports are chosen accordingly. Now, whether this is a good idea to use standard ports with nonstandard assignment is another matter.

Comment: Thanks! I am just using usb c cable, not the connector. The connector side uses LEMO 12pin on one end and other end is 12v power + USB 2.0 + ethernet. I just need a cable but don't want to buy a whole lot of special cable with a few hundred meters in length.